# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout? What should I do?

Tags: java, android

Today I'm having this issue with my application; I want to say that *I read almost ALL the other questions here on StackOverflow but nothing*, always the same problem.

**homepage.java** (main class)

```
 public class homepage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_homepage, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = null;
            switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
            {
                case 1:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fibra, container, false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adsl, container, false);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aiuto, container, false);
                    break;
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java** (default code from Android Studio Guide)

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> 
{
private String[] mDataset;
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v;
        }
    }
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

And finally, one of the fragment that I'm using:

**fibra.java**

```
public class fibra extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private LinearLayoutManager llm;
String [] prova={"prova1","prova2","prova2","prova2","prova2","prova2","prova2"};

public fibra() {
}
public static fibra newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    fibra fragment = new fibra();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setContentView(R.layout.my_activity); (doesn't work "cannot resolve method")

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); //per migliorare performance

    llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    adapter = new MyAdapter(prova);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fibra, container, false);
    return rootView;

}
// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Comment: Where does error occur ?

Comment: When I try to switch to the "fibra fragment".

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
//setContentView(R.layout.my_activity); (doesn't work "cannot resolve method")
```

It's like inflating a layout inside an `Activity` which you already have `onCreateView` and **in a `Fragment`.**

Change the first codes to :

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

Then, initialize `RecyclerView` inside `onCreateView()`.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fibra, container, false);
        // Here you should initialize RecyclerView and other widgets by rootView.findViewById and etc
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); //per migliorare performance

        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        adapter = new MyAdapter(prova);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;

    }
```

Comment: Nothing, same problem :(

Comment: You also forgot to add `tablaylout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);` as mentioned by other user but that wasn't just the case. Now, tab opens or not?

Comment: I put that string in the "onCreate" method of homepage.java, but I always have the same problem and now, with that string, I can't see the menù items!

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add `tablaylout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);` in your `homepage.java`

Comment: Same problem, but now I can't see the menù items!

Comment: may be the problem of menu items just because of your styles.xml or color control or icon color. can you share your <code>menu_homepage.xml</code>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#E60000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#cc0000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="background">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
BUT for each fragment i'm using this color "#EFEFEF", not the one that you see here in the colors.xml file

Comment: if you to show menu in fragments than add this line setHasOptionsMenu(true); in fragment's onCreateView method.

Comment: Nothing, same problem